# WP link not showing properly on linkedin

Tags: html, wordpress, linkedin-api, blogs

I am starting a new blog and was testing out sharing on linkedIn.

However, when I copy and paste the link into the share thing in linkedin, the blog doesn't show up properly.

Would you be able to help me understand what I would need to add to my blog post to make it show up correctly?

To add some more info: I do have a featured image set, and the blog post does have a title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mine:

[image: Current]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing a "rich" link when pasting it is likely because you do not have your [Open Graphs meta tags](http://ogp.me) set up properly.

You can simply use a plugin with Wordpress to add these tags, [like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/) or you can [learn how to program it yourself into your theme](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-open-graph-tags-to-wordpress).

[Facebook has a good debugger for tags](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), which you can use to check your links.

You can read more about how og tags are used by LinkedIn in their [developer article](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin).